# launch4j создаёт exe, но всё равно требует java на другом компьютере

Tags: java, развертывание

В чём смысл launch4j если он создаёт exe-файл который может запуститься на компе только если есть установленная jre? Ведь jar-файлы и так запускаются, если есть jre.

Comment: это просто удобный запуск с плюшками

Comment: @DmitryTerentjev То есть эта программа не решает вопрос с запуском java-программ под windows? Почему же тогда в тематических вопросах предлагают использовать launch4j для создания exe-файлов?

Comment: Лучше [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html) используйте.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev А если java 8? javapackager?

Comment: @LogIN `launch4j` просто пакует Вашу программу в `exe` файл. Сама Java туда не входит.

Comment: @LogIN [да](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Я ничего не понял, я сделал как написано в примере 7-2 и сгенерировались только .html и .jnlp файлы и что дальше?